# How to get Firebase Data into a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing an Android App. I have been successful in writing to Firebase, I however am having a problem reading from Firebase into a ListView. If anyone can assist in getting the data to read back into the app into the ListView, If i just have one item to try and read back it works if I try to get all three items the app fails.
I have included a picture of the Database to get an idea of the structure and my code.

[image]

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Admin_ViewEvent extends AppCompatActivity {

   // private TextView textViewPersons;
private ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<String> mMeetings = new ArrayList<>();
private Firebase mRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin__view_event);

    mRef = new Firebase("https://saica-sgb-77a4f.firebaseio.com/Meetings");
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    //textViewPersons = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPersons);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMeetings);
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String date = (String) childSnapShot.child("address").getValue();
                String datetime = (String) childSnapShot.child("datetime").getValue();
                String name = (String) childSnapShot.child("name").getValue();

                mMeetings.add(date);
                mMeetings.add(datetime);
                mMeetings.add(name);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

 }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code? The only thing I quickly see is that you fail to call `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onDataChange()`. I would also recommend using a `ChildEventListener`, since that allows you to more granularly update the list view and thus get less screen flicker.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, what i would like to happen is get each item in a list of its own as each item in the Firebase becomes an item of its own. eg, the first key the 3 items must be grouped up and displayed.

Comment: Sounds like a clear use-case. What doesn't work about the current code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Firebase UI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).

Just add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI Database only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
}
```

Then define a simple class to map your object:

```
public class MyObject {

   private String name;
   private String address;
   private String dateTime;

   public MyObject() {
   }
   ....

}
```

Then just use something like:

```
mRef = new Firebase("https://saica-sgb-77a4f.firebaseio.com/Meetings");
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<MyObject>(this, MyObject.class, R.layout.myLayout, mRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, MyObject myObj, int position) {
           //Set the value for the views
           ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.xxx)).setText(myObj.getName());
           //...
        }
    };
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Hi is there no other way besides using Firebaseui as I have tried Firebase UI and it seemed to cause problems in the app.

Comment: @JNR_Prog123 You have to choose the right version according to the firebase version used in your app.
It is just an Adapter, nothing more: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseListAdapter.java

Answer (score 1):

Use ChildEventListener and put your this code:
 
 `final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMeetings);
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);`

inside the onChildAdded....
Also creat Model class to get data from firebase
public class User {public String name;public String date;public String time;// Default constructor required for calls to 
`// DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
public User() {}public User(String name, String time, String date) {this.name = name;
this.time= time;this.date=date;}`
thanks it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something, you should add this

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getReference
.child("Meetings").child(uid);
```

and then in the onDataChange.

```
String date = (String) childSnapShot.child("address").getValue();
            String datetime = (String) childSnapShot.child("datetime").getValue();
            String name = (String) childSnapShot.child("name").getValue();

            mMeetings.add(date);
            mMeetings.add(datetime);
            mMeetings.add(name);
```