# Increment the value of an Int using a button from a custom listview layout

Tags: java, android, listview, button

I have recently managed to make a custom listview layout and populate that data from a listview.
The listview contains a "Like" Button and a  textview storing the amount of likes. Yet i cant seem to figure out how to take that int and increment it on button press as the will be performed in the CustomAdapter.

Data Model:

```
public class MessagesListDataModel {
 private String uid;
 private String msg;
 private String likes;
 private String date;
 private Button like;
 private Button reply;


public MessagesListDataModel(String uid, String msg, String date) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.msg = msg;
    this.date = date;
    this.likes = likes;
}
public MessagesListDataModel(){

}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
public String getLikes() {
    return likes;
}

public void setLikes(String likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Button getLike() {
    return like;
}

public void setLike(Button like) {
    this.like = like;
}
}
```

The Adapter:

```
public class MessagesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessagesListDataModel> {

private ArrayList<MessagesListDataModel> dataModels;

public MessagesListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessagesListDataModel> dataModels){
    super(context,0, dataModels);
    this.dataModels = dataModels;

}

/*
 * we are overriding the getView method here - this is what defines how each
 * list item will look.
 */
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    MessagesListDataModel messagesListDataModel = dataModels.get(position);

    // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
    // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_messages_layout, parent, false);
    }


        TextView uid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserID);
        TextView message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
        TextView likes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLikes);
        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDateTime);
        Button like = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLike);
        Button reply = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonReply);

        uid.setText(messagesListDataModel.getUid());
        message.setText(messagesListDataModel.getMsg());
        date.setText(messagesListDataModel.getDate());
        likes.setText(messagesListDataModel.getLikes());

        like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Like button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                //Increment the value of the likes textview and reload that textview to display new likes. Limit the likes to only be able to like a post once.

            }
        });

        reply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "reply button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                //passing data for the reference in the replies class.



            }
        });

    return convertView;


}
}
```

In the like.SetOnClickListener, how can i retrieve data from firebase database stored as "likes", update the int by adding 1 and store it back into the database?

Can this even be done in the adapter or does this need to take place in the "main activity" of where the data gets populated? Im not sure how to go about this.

Also another problem is that the textviews dont accept Int's so i need to be converting from string to int and back when doing this?

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);

    //for sending messages to database
    btn_send_msg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    input_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_Input);

    //Date time
    //DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    //dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    //Date date = new Date();
    //String dtSent = ((dateFormat.format(date).toString()));



    //UserData student ID
    FirebaseUser loggedinFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String userId = loggedinFirebaseUser.getUid();

    room_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("room_name").toString();
    setTitle(" Room - " + room_name);


    //stores the reference as a string to be passed onto the userDataReference table
    databaseUrlRef = "users/userData" + "/" + userId;
    userDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(databaseUrlRef + "/SID");
    chatroomsref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatrooms").child(room_name);

    ///////
    final MessagesListAdapter arrayAdapter = new MessagesListAdapter(this,arrayMessages);

    ListViewMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatRoomMessagesListview);
    ListViewMessages.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    chatroomsref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //fetchData();
            //for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MessagesListDataModel messagesListDataModel =
                        dataSnapshot.getValue(MessagesListDataModel.class);
                arrayMessages.add(messagesListDataModel);

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    /////
    //reference to the database that is within the chatrooms and the room name of the name that was clicked and passed onto this activity.
    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatrooms/" + room_name);

    userDataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String Name = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            user_name = Name;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891268/how-to-get-firebase-data-into-a-listview
    btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String dtSent = ((dateFormat.format(date).toString()));

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();
            // temp key is the randomly generated key
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
            Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("uid", user_name);
            map2.put("msg", input_msg.getText().toString());
            map2.put("likes","0");
            map2.put("date",dtSent);

            message_root.updateChildren(map2);
            input_msg.setText("");
        }
    });

}
}
```

What im mainly looking for is how could i access this(Chatrooms/RoomName/UNIQUE_ID/likes) as structured in the database, and update it. Where the Unique id is an actual unique id.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.brunelcs.group13.anyquestions, PID: 8808
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
>                         at com.brunelcs.group13.anyquestions.ChatRoom$1.onButtonClick(ChatRoom.java:87)
>                         at com.brunelcs.group13.anyquestions.MessagesListAdapter$1.onClick(MessagesListAdapter.java:81)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getPostKey.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
```

that i put after getPostKey,

and the other one:

```
if (btnClickListener != null)
                    btnClickListener.onButtonClick((Integer) view.getTag());}
```

Also the arrayAdapter had to be changed to this as it was comming up with errors:

```
 final MessagesListAdapter arrayAdapter = new  MessagesListAdapter(this, arrayMessages, new MessagesListAdapter.ButtonClickListener() {}
```

This is how i am posting the data into firebase:

```
btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String dtSent = ((dateFormat.format(date).toString()));

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();
            // temp key is the randomly generated key
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
            Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("uid", user_name);
            map2.put("msg", input_msg.getText().toString());
            map2.put("likes","0");
            map2.put("date",dtSent);

            message_root.updateChildren(map2);
            input_msg.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to retrieve data in this case number of likes from specific item/post then make increment and save it again. To implement click on specific `View` inside the adapter you can create an `interface` for example this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132359/how-do-i-add-an-onclicklistener-to-a-button-inside-a-listview-adapter

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315353/update-specific-values-using-firebase-for-android but how can i get the key? that is set in the main method and not the adapter

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from answer I posted you in comment you can create an interface inside your `Adapter` class with one `void` method and `int` as parametar for example:

```
public interface ButtonClickListener {
   public abstract void onButtonClick(int position);
}
```

Then use this in constructor of your adapter class so you can `override` it inside your `Activity` and preform `ButtonClick`. For example:

```
private ButtonClickListener btnClickListener = null;
public MessagesListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessagesListDataModel> dataModels, ButtonClickListener btnClickListener){
super(context,0, dataModels);
this.dataModels = dataModels;
this.btnClickListener = btnClickListener;
}
```

After that inside your `Adapter` class `setTag` on `like` button and `setOnclickListener` on it and get the tag. For example:

```
likes.setTag(position);
likes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if(btnClickListener != null)
        btnClickListener.onButtonClick((Integer) v.getTag());                
   }
});
```

When you are done with this you will be able to implement click listener inside your adapter creation in `Activity` and then inside using `position` get the key of post and with that key, retrieve how many likes you have on specific post, make increment and set the value again. Create a new `getter` and `setter` inside your model class to store `key` for example:

```
private String postKey;

public String getPostKey() {
    return postKey;
}

public void setPostKey(String postKey) {
    this.postKey = postKey;
}
```

You will need to store the key inside `sePostKey` so you can get the key from `getPostKey`. And then you can easily get it from your `MessagesListDataModel`:

```
final MessagesListAdapter arrayAdapter = new  MessagesListAdapter(this,arrayMessages, new ButtonClickListener(){
 @Override
  public void onButtonClick(int position) {
   String getPostKey = arrayMessages.get(position).getPostKey();
  //Now you have a key to run another query to get data from specific post and with that number of likes as well
   }
});
```

Probably process could be simplified or to use some another better approach  but this is just an idea how you could achieve what you want. I didn't test this code I hope it will work.

Comment: What is getRef? am i supposed to make a function to return it in the Model class? or? it comes up as cannot resolve method.

Comment: Yeah sorry `getRef()` is only accessible on `datasnapshot` another solution is to create a new `getter` and `setter` inside your model class and set the key and then get the key. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I have made the changes and also added a toast to see if when the button is pressed is gets the correct key. However, it displays a null reference error for two things. see edits please.

Comment: How do you getting the `key` did you store it in database and then retrieve  or?

Comment: i dont understand. i thought that what you helped me with was supposed to get the Unique key(e.g "-L4WoFJpI1vnFcCEj8Ss") of the item in the listview of that the button was pressed, so that i can make a reference a get the child object i want to update after?

Comment: Yes but seems you are not storing the key inside `setPostKey` and probably that is why you are getting `null pointer exception`

Comment: For example in your `Toast` change the `getPostKey.toString()` into `String.valueOf(getPostKey.toString());` and see will `Toast` post a `null` as message.

Comment: Can i make it work with the way i store the data into firebase? or do i need to refactor it to use my model class?, added to edits.

Comment: If you can not get the post key directly you could store it inside database with rest of your post info like: message, date etc and then retrieve it with rest data.

Comment: Doesnt that pose the same problem as original? if i store it inside, in order to retrieve it on the button click i will still need the key to get inside that "Message" to retrieve the key?

Comment: I am considering a different walkaround this problem where i can implement, OnItemClick and do this String key = adapter.getRef(position).getKey(), and OnItemLongClick to handle the other replies button.

Comment: No because as with all rest of data which you get for your posts like: `messages`, `dates` etc you will also get `post keys` and as you store that data inside `MessagesListDataModel` you will also store keys. I just tried to help you with performing click on specific post like (as that was your actual question) but how are you going to get a key and run another query that is something that you will need to struggle with. If you are going to be a programmer and live from that then struggling is something that you will have do too often.

Comment: yes i do realise this , thank you for the help, i shall continue the struggle and hopefully get this sorted.