# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter crashes every time app starts

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Hi i'm trying to add a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to my app so users can scroll through their news feed and see recent posts. The images and information is stored in Firebase then is retrived from the user but the app keeps crashing with no error in the logcat and also date, time and description is not displayed in Firebase database using the hashmap, could that be the cause of the problem?

Please help  .

post class:

```
public class post {
    public String Uid,time,date,postimage,fullname,description,profileimage;

    public post(){

    }



    public post(String uid, String time, String date, String postimage, String fullname, String description, String profileimage) {
        Uid = uid;
        this.time = time;
        this.date = date;
        this.postimage = postimage;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.description = description;
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return Uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        Uid = uid;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getPostimage() {
        return postimage;
    }

    public void setPostimage(String postimage) {
        this.postimage = postimage;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getProfileimage() {
        return profileimage;
    }

    public void setProfileimage(String profileimage) {
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
    }
}
```

post activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        add_post_image= findViewById(R.id.post);
        description =findViewById(R.id.image_description);
        upload=findViewById(R.id.upload_button);
        postReference =FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        postref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("post");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        loadingbar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mToolbar=findViewById(R.id.post_action_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Update Post");

        add_post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendusertogallery();
            }
        });
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validateuserinformation();
            }
        });

    }

    private void validateuserinformation() {
        String Description = description.getText().toString();
        if (imageuri==null){
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"please select image/video that u wish to post...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Description)){
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"please add description for your image/video",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else {

            loadingbar.setTitle("adding new post");
            loadingbar.setMessage("please wait ....");
            loadingbar.show();
            loadingbar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            Storingmediatofirebasestorage();
        }
    }

    private void Storingmediatofirebasestorage() {
        Calendar callforddate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentdate =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        savecurrentdate= currentdate.format(callforddate.getTime());

        Calendar calFordTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        savecurrenttime = currentTime.format(callforddate.getTime());

        postrandomname =savecurrentdate + savecurrenttime;

        StorageReference filepath = postReference.child("post image").child(imageuri.getLastPathSegment()+postrandomname + ".jpg");

        filepath.putFile(imageuri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"image uploaded successfully to storage",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Task<Uri> result = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();

                    result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();

                            userRef.child(current_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    String userfullname =dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                                    String userprofileimages = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();

                                    HashMap postsMap = new HashMap();
                                    postsMap.put("uid", current_user_id);
                                    postsMap.put("date", savecurrentdate);
                                    postsMap.put("time", savecurrenttime);
                                    postsMap.put("description", Description);
                                    postsMap.put("postimage", downloadUrl);
                                    postsMap.put("profileimage", userprofileimages);
                                    postsMap.put("fullname",userfullname);
                                    postref.child(current_user_id + postrandomname).updateChildren(postsMap)
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                        SENDUSERTOMAINACTIVITY();
                                                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"new post is updated successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        loadingbar.dismiss();
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Error! "+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        loadingbar.dismiss();
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });



                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });



                        }
                    });


                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void sendusertogallery() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLARY_PICK);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==GALLARY_PICK && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!= null){
            imageuri = data.getData();
            add_post_image.setImageURI(imageuri);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            SENDUSERTOMAINACTIVITY();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void SENDUSERTOMAINACTIVITY() {
        Intent mainactivityintent = new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainactivityintent);
    }
}
```

main activity:

```
 private void DisplayAllUsersPosts() {
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<post> options=
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<post>()
                    .setQuery(postreference,post.class)
                    .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post,postholder> adapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postholder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull postholder holder, int position, @NonNull post model) {
                holder.username1.setText(model.getFullname());
                holder.date1.setText(model.getDate());
                holder.time1.setText(model.getTime());
                holder.postdescription.setText(model.getDescription());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getPostimage()).into(holder.postted_image);
                Picasso.get().load(model.getProfileimage()).into(holder.post_profilepicture);

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public postholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_post_layout,parent, false);
                postholder viewholder = new postholder(view);
                return viewholder;
            }
        };
        postlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

    }


    public static class postholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView username1, date1, time1, postdescription;
        CircleImageView post_profilepicture;
        ImageView postted_image;




        View mView;
        public postholder(@NonNull View itemView) {


            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;

            username1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
            date1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            time1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            postdescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
           post_profilepicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_post_image);
            postted_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_view);


        }
    }
```

stacktrace :

```
02/04 10:21:16: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk C:\PROJECTS\BFit\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed in 12 s 574 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "aj_studio.bfit/aj_studio.bfit.Login" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 27880 on device samsung-sm_g925i-05157df5484e863d
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/lib/arm64
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 94pYST3YcGegYCjnOpQ9DTYDtDs1 ).
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
V/FA: Collection enabled
    App package, google app id: aj_studio.bfit, 1:1041467221265:android:c6621db46ea28f6a
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 14710
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app aj_studio.bfit
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/InstantRun: Starting server socket listening for package aj_studio.bfit on android.net.LocalSocketAddress@defa118
V/InstantRun: Started server for package aj_studio.bfit
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/FA: onActivityCreated
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void aj_studio.bfit.Login.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Login.java:33)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void aj_studio.bfit.Login.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Login.java:33)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.242ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 459(24KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 19MB/33MB, paused 9.153ms total 34.289ms
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
V/FA: onActivityCreated
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.flags.IFlagProvider$Stub>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/stable/zzb;
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Singletons.<init>() ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Singletons.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagRegistry com.google.android.gms.flags.Singletons.flagRegistry() ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag.<init>(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag.<init>(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, com.google.android.gms.flags.zza) ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag$BooleanFlag.<init>(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean) ((null):-1)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag$BooleanFlag com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag.define(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean) ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzx.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzx.initialize(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzt.run() ((null):-1)
        at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:751)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:95)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.os.HandlerThread.run() (HandlerThread.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.stable.zzb" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Singletons.<init>() ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Singletons.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagRegistry com.google.android.gms.flags.Singletons.flagRegistry() ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag.<init>(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag.<init>(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, com.google.android.gms.flags.zza) ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag$BooleanFlag.<init>(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean) ((null):-1)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag$BooleanFlag com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag.define(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean) ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzx.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzx.initialize(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
        at void com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzt.run() ((null):-1)
        at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:751)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:95)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.os.HandlerThread.run() (HandlerThread.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: TokenRefresher
    Process: aj_studio.bfit, PID: 27880
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING of type Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in /data/app/aj_studio.bfit-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagValueProvider.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagRegistry.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzx.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzt.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27880 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo i uploaded the stack trace to the question ...

Comment: Please indicate the exact line of code at which the error occurs.

Comment: @AlexMamo i notice in the Stack trace it says  "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: uid"

Comment: In this case, please add it to your question the content of your `post.class`.

Comment: @AlexMamo  the content is already there .. its the first set of code

Comment: I tried that and it doesn’t work I commented out the getter and setter uid in the post activity and it’s working ..but that’s for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: uid"

Because in your `post.class` you have the `Uid` property which is starting with a capital letter. The way you can solve this is mentioned in my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069574/firebase-android-listview-not-being-displayed)**.

Comment: Thanks ...but can u tell me why description ,time and date is not showing in firebase database using the hashmap

Comment: You're welcome but regarding your second question, I'm not sure that I understand it. But it seems to be beyond the scope of this question. If you want to get a detailed answer regarding this second issue, which cannot be provided here in a comment, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I’ll add the question in a moment

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem happens for vector drawable.
Use vector drawable true in your app level gradle file.

**build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
android {
    defaultConfig{
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```