# In Firebase Real time Database , How can I iterate through each product and display their details in a recycler view

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is how my database looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8i1I.png)

[image]

I wanted to iterate through all the child node just like this and retrieve value from their respective child node But I am unable to do that please suggest anyway to do that.
The code for fragment on which the list needs to be shown is below

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Product> productList;
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        initData();
        initRecyclerView();
        return v;
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        ProductAdapter productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(productList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
    }

    private void initData() {
        String user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            String pname = snapshot.child("pname").getValue(String.class);
                            String pdesc = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                            String price = dataSnapshot.child("price").getValue(String.class);
                            String imgURL = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                            productList.add(new Product(pname,price,pdesc,imgURL));

                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });

    }


}
```

The code for product adapter class is given below

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductVH> {

    private static final String TAG = "ProductAdapter";
    List<Product> productList;

    public ProductAdapter(List<Product> productList) {
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
        return new ProductVH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductVH holder, int position) {
        Product product = productList.get(position);
        holder.prodName.setText(product.getProductName());
        holder.prodPrice.setText(product.getProductPrice());
        holder.prodDesc.setText(product.getProductDesc());

        boolean isExpanded = productList.get(position).isExpanded();
        holder.expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }





    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    public class ProductVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private static final String TAG = "ProductVH";
        ConstraintLayout expandableLayout;
        TextView prodName , prodPrice , prodDesc ;
        ImageView productImage , delete , instock , edit;

        public ProductVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            expandableLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);
            prodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_list_name);
            prodPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_list_price);
            prodDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_description);
            productImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            instock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.in_stock);
            edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);


            prodName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Product product = productList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    product.setExpanded(!product.isExpanded());
                    notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The Product class is given below

```
public class Product {
    String productName,productDesc, productPrice,imgURI;
    private boolean expanded;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String productName, String productDesc, String productPrice, String imgURI) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productDesc = productDesc;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.imgURI = imgURI;
    }



    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductDesc() {
        return productDesc;
    }

    public void setProductDesc(String productDesc) {
        this.productDesc = productDesc;
    }

    public String getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(String productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getImgURI() {
        return imgURI;
    }

    public void setImgURI(String imgURI) {
        this.imgURI = imgURI;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movie{" +
                "Product name ='" + productName + '\'' +
                ", price ='" + productPrice + '\'' +
                ", product descrition ='" + productDesc + '\'' +
                ", image ='" + imgURI + '\'' +
                ", expanded=" + expanded +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54578292/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firebase-and-show-them-in-textview

Comment: Post the erroneous code so we can help you.

Comment: @Makdous I have posted my code sir

Comment: add the database image to the question, not as link.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam I have added the database image sir

Comment: Please indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: I want to get the value of pname, description, price, image of each child node of the  parent node

Answer (score 0):

Your Data reading seems fine:

**Move this line:**

```
initRecyclerView();
```

**Directly after the for loop here:**

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String pname = snapshot.child("pname").getValue(String.class);
                        String pdesc = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                        String price = dataSnapshot.child("price").getValue(String.class);
                        String imgURL = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                        productList.add(new Product(pname,price,pdesc,imgURL));

                    }

                //here
                initRecyclerView();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: when I did that The app crashes When I tap the home button.The logcat show this error     `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.prj.ProductAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ProductAdapter.java:36)
        at com.example.prj.ProductAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ProductAdapter.java:15)`