# How to retrieve all location Longitude and latitude from Firebase and put marker on google map api for android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps

I understand that this question is consider as similar qiestion, but, I really can't solved and i am just newbie trying to learn android.

So, the expecting outcome was having an activity which is google map to allow user itself to look at their SavedPlace. So my cloud firestore structure look like this now:

[image: cloud firestore structure]

Then, in my code, what i did so far is:

```
    public class FoodShareActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar mtoolbar;
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    FusedLocationProviderClient client;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private DatabaseReference mDataRef;
    Marker marker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_share);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("FoodShare");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_baseline_keyboard_backspace_24);

        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FoodShareActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getCurrentLocation();

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FoodShareActivity.this, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 44
            );
        }

        ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
//        mDataRef.push().setValue(marker);
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                                            location.getLongitude());
                                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Im hrer");
                                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,17.0f));
                                    googleMap.addMarker(options);
                            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("SavedPlace");
                        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    placeModel post = postSnapshot.getValue(placeModel.class);
                                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(post.getLat()));
                                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(post.getLong()));

                                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                                    markerOptions.title(post.getPlaceName());
                                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

                                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { }
                        });


                                }
                            });
                        }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return false;
    }
}
```

For my placeModel,

```
public class placeModel {
    private String placeAddress;
    private String placeDetails;
    private String placeLatLong;
    private String placeName;
    private String placeNote;
    double Lat;
    double Long;

    public placeModel(){
        //empty constuctor needed
    }

    public placeModel(String placeAddress, String placeDetails, String placeLatLong, String placeName, String placeNote, double Lat, double Long) {
        this.placeAddress = placeAddress;
        this.placeDetails = placeDetails;
        this.placeLatLong = placeLatLong;

        this.placeName = placeName;
        this.placeNote = placeNote;
        this.Lat = Lat;
        this.Long = Long;

    }


    public String getPlaceAddress() {
        return placeAddress;
    }
    public String getPlaceName() { return placeName; }
    public double getLat() {
        Log.d("ga", "checkAA"+ Lat);

        return Lat;
    }
    public double getLong() { return Long; }


    public String getDetails() {
        return placeDetails;
    }
    public String getLatLong() { return placeLatLong; }
    public String getNote() { return placeNote; }

}
```

The map acitivty works fine, and able to see my current location. But the marker for location from database doennt show.

[image: Current outcome]

The final outcome that is to have multiple marker on google map marking based on latitude and longitude from firebase.

PLEASE HELP ME, I STUCK HERE FOR ABOUT 2 DAYS.

Comment: `However, the latitude and longitude from firebase does not work` could you explain ? what is it doing ? what isn't it doing ?

Comment: Sorry for that, So, what i mean actually is it doesnt show any marker except the current location. What i want actually is to have all the location in firebase

Comment: You will not be able to use `lat` and `long` if you don't change the names in the database to start with a lower letter, as well in your class. You can also use an annotation, as explained in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069574/firebase-android-listview-not-being-displayed).

Comment: I've changed it, still the same, just nothing happen over there. I've also tried to use Log.d to debug, it wont run Log in this page.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing in android So customise my code and it may help you.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Dams");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Dam post = postSnapshot.getValue(Dam.class);
                    damsList.add(post);
                    
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(post.getDamLat()));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(post.getDamLong()));

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title(post.getDamLevel());
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
                }

                pd.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                pd.dismiss();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey there, Thank you so much for that. May I know whats damsList.add(post); actually means. Anyway, thanks ya.

Comment: You can remove it. It is a list of posts that i am retrieving from the fire-base

Comment: Alright, after i customise your version, the marker still doenst came out. I've updated the latest code above my question. Could you please help me to check it, Please. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Check out if data is coming from the fire-base